# Turn off / Disable Renown Rewards

Tags: diablo-iv

I want to have a play-through like my first one, or let my brother try the game, but every new char starts quite "twinked" / especially those 10 skill points.

Can I turn off or disable account-wide renown rewards?

Comment: Microsoft would be happy if you bought another copy!